# Debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in project "ReactiveObjC") (in target 'ReactiveObjC-iOS')

Tags: ios, xcode

When I manually configured `ReactiveObjc`, I followed the configuration tutorial provided by `ReactiveObjc` to manually configure it step by step. But the final program reports an error:

Showing Recent Messages

> :-1:
>   /Users/.../Desktop/RACtest/ReactiveObjc/ReactiveObjC-master/Carthage/Checkouts/xcconfigs/Base/Configurations/Debug.xcconfig:
>   unable to open file (in project "ReactiveObjC") (in target
>   'ReactiveObjC-iOS')

There are six identical errors, all of which say disable to open file (in project "ReactiveObjC") (in target `'ReactiveObjC-iOS`'). Sorry, I can't provide an image to show the specific content. I confirm that I followed the tutorial step by step configuration.I really don't know how to solve this problem. can you help me?

Comment: Provide the link to the tutorial. It looks like you have not configured the `.xcconfig` file correctly with the Xcode project.